# Translating MySql query into Django ORM query

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

I have a query in MySql that I need translated into Django ORM. It involves joining on two tables with two counts on one of the tables. I'm pretty close to it in Django but I get duplicate results. Here's the query:

```
SELECT au.id, 
       au.username, 
       COALESCE(orders_ct, 0) AS orders_ct, 
       COALESCE(clean_ct, 0)  AS clean_ct, 
       COALESCE(wash_ct, 0)   AS wash_ct 
FROM   auth_user AS au 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN 
           ( SELECT user_id,
                    Count(*)  AS orders_ct                    
             FROM   `order`
             GROUP  BY user_id
           ) AS o 
                    ON au.id = o.user_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN  
           ( SELECT user_id,
                    Count(CASE WHEN service = 'clean' THEN 1 
                          END)  AS clean_ct,
                    Count(CASE WHEN service = 'wash' THEN 1 
                          END)  AS wash_ct                            
             FROM   job
             GROUP  BY user_id
           ) AS j
                    ON au.id = j.user_id 
ORDER  BY au.id DESC 
LIMIT  100 ;
```

My current Django query (which brings back unwanted duplicates):

```
User.objects.annotate(
    orders_ct = Count( 'orders', distinct = True )
).annotate(
    clean_ct = Count( Case(
        When( job__service__exact = 'clean', then = 1 )
    ) )
).annotate(
    wash_ct = Count( Case(
        When( job__service__exact = 'wash', then = 1 )
    ) )
)
```

The above Django code produces the following query which is close but not right:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `auth_user`.`id`, 
                `auth_user`.`username`, 
                Count(DISTINCT `order`.`id`) AS `orders_ct`, 
                Count(CASE 
                        WHEN `job`.`service` = 'clean' THEN 1 
                        ELSE NULL 
                      end)                   AS `clean_ct`, 
                Count(CASE 
                        WHEN `job`.`service` = 'wash' THEN 1 
                        ELSE NULL 
                      end)                   AS `wash_ct` 
FROM   `auth_user` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `order` 
                    ON ( `auth_user`.`id` = `order`.`user_id` ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `job` 
                    ON ( `auth_user`.`id` = `job`.`user_id` ) 
GROUP  BY `auth_user`.`id` 
ORDER  BY `auth_user`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT  100
```

I could probably achieve it by doing some [raw sql subqueries](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/236/) but I would like to remain as abstract as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/130009), you can write:

```
User.objects.annotate(
    orders_ct = Count( 'orders', distinct = True ),
    clean_ct = Count( Case(
        When( job__service__exact = 'clean', then = F('job__pk') )
    ), distinct = True ),
    wash_ct = Count( Case(
        When( job__service__exact = 'wash', then = F('job__pk') )
    ), distinct = True )
)
```

Table (after joins):

```
user.id  order.id  job.id  job.service  your case/when  my case/when
1        1         1       wash         1               1
1        1         2       wash         1               2
1        1         3       clean        NULL            NULL
1        1         4       other        NULL            NULL
1        2         1       wash         1               1
1        2         2       wash         1               2
1        2         3       clean        NULL            NULL
1        2         4       other        NULL            NULL
```

Desired output for `wash_ct` is 2. Counting distinct values in `my case/when`, we will get 2.

Comment: This will bring all my counts to 0 or 1 since I count distinct values which means it will eliminate everything else so it will count only one record or none.

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea Added table.

Comment: I had the distinct on counts tried earlier and it didn't work. That `F` thingie did it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, the chained annotation of job might have produced duplicate users.

If not can you elaborate on duplicates you are seeing.

```
User.objects.annotate(
    orders_ct = Count( 'orders', distinct = True )
).annotate(
    clean_ct = Count( Case(
        When( job__service__exact = 'clean', then = 1 )
    ) ),
    wash_ct = Count( Case(
        When( job__service__exact = 'wash', then = 1 )
    ) )
)
```

Comment: produces same query. nothing really to elaborate, django's query produces duplicates because of the two left outer joins. See this accepted answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129982/mysql-counting-results-with-left-joins-doubles-the-results

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `values()`, also when `distinct=True` you can [combine `Count()`'s in one `annotation()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations).

```
Users.objects.values("id").annotate(
    orders_ct = Count('orders', distinct = True)
    ).annotate(
    clean_ct = Count(Case(When(job__service__exact='clean', then=1)),
               distinct = True),
    wash_ct = Count(Case(When(job__service__exact='wash',then=1)),
              distinct = True)
    ).values("id", "username", "orders_ct", "clean_ct", "wash_сt")
```

Using `values("id")` should add `GROUP BY 'id'` for annotations and therefore prevent duplicates, see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#values).

Also, there's [`Coalesce`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce), but it doesn't look like it's needed, since `Count()` returns `int` anyway. And [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct), but again the `distinct` in `Count()` should be enough.

Not sure if `Case` needed inside `Count()` as it should count them anyway.

Comment: I don't think you can count that way in Django: `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'expression'`

Comment: @Romeo Mihalcea, modified the query to look more like the original one, which `Count`'s you claimed work. My main point is not in `Count` itself, but to use `values` to get `GROUP BY` and join annotations in one. Please, check if it helps.